# Why isn't my simple Javascript to enable and disable a button based on Recaptcha success & timeout working?

Tags: javascript

I think I'm going a little mad.

I have a working re-captcha div and submit button:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="LALALALALAL" data-callback="enableBtn"></div>
<br />
<button id="getJSON" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Form</button>
```

The Save Form button is disabled on page load.

I have the following function:

```
<script>
function enableBtn(){

  var submit = document.getElementById('getJSON');

     if (submit.disabled) {

        document.getElementById("getJSON").disabled = false;

    } else {

        document.getElementById("getJSON").disabled = true;
    }
  }

  </script>
```

The callback works fine for the initial enabling of the button on successful recaptcha response, but when the recaptcha times out the button doesn't get disabled.

As I said, I think I'm going a little mad.

Comment: First, you can replace the if else with `button.disabled = !submit.disabled`. Second, make sure you execute the function whenever the forms state changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use `data-expired-callback` attribute.

```html
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="LALALALALAL" data-callback="enableBtn" data-expired-callback="enableBtn"></div>
<br />
<button id="getJSON" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Form</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realised there was a separate call back for expiry. Works perfectly now.